# Searchbar from xml file to listview

Tags: c#, xml, listview, search

I read my files from a XML document and put them i a listview. And i want to add a searchbar so i can filter all the information in the listview. But when i serch for exampel index2 the lines from the listview will show the correct information (content of index2 item) but the saved XML text will wright the information from index1 instead of index2. Beacuse the index2 now has index1 so it gets the wrong information.
This is my basic delete code but i think this is done correct.

Then i search for pat and the listview is correct but the information is wrong: 
[image]

```
        if (txtSearch.Text != "")
        {
            for (int i = listPeople.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                var item = listPeople.Items[i];
                if (item.Text.ToLower().Contains(txtSearch.Text.ToLower()))
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    listPeople.Items.Remove(item);
                }
            }
            if (listPeople.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                listPeople.Focus();
                people.RemoveAt(listPeople.SelectedItems[0].Index);
                listPeople.Items.Remove(listPeople.SelectedItems[0]);
            }
```

Comment: search steps:1 https://gyazo.com/142ae250ee030cc9d708a69754a946ed  2 https://gyazo.com/ad45f8b0816691c6a967837f43d43cd3                              3 https://gyazo.com/36749c5112706c9fbdb9acec248700de

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add indexes. and finally u can correctly delete.
For example

```
 if (txtSearch.Text != "")
    {
        List<int> indexes = new List<int>();
        for (int i = listPeople.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            var item = listPeople.Items[i];
            if (item.Text.ToLower().Contains(txtSearch.Text.ToLower()))
            {
            }
            else
            {
                indexes.add(i);
            }
        }
        foreach(int index in indexes)
        {
              //delete with index
        }
        if (listPeople.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {

            listPeople.Focus();
            people.RemoveAt(listPeople.SelectedItems[0].Index);
            listPeople.Items.Remove(listPeople.SelectedItems[0]);
        }
```